# Unable to view/delete Postgres Index

Tags: postgresql

I've created an index

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_id_test ON br.deals (id);
```

to view all indices I ran this:

```
\di+
```

but its completely empty

however when I run this:

```
 \d br.deals
```

I see the following:

```
                         Table "br.deals"
     Column      |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id              | bigint            |           |          | 
 start_date      | character varying |           |          | 
 end_date        | character varying |           |          | 
 name            | character varying |           |          | 

Indexes:
    "deals_ukey" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "index_id_test" btree (id)
```

I tried to delete this index because it was just a test:

```
DROP INDEX index_id_test;
```

but I see:

> index "index_id_test" does not exist

I'm not sure what I had created earlier if not an index because I also tried this but it comes up empty:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'deals';
```

Comment: I thing an index is always created in the parent tables schema. The schema here is "br" and the table is "deals". So the correct statement should be `DROP INDEX br.index_id_test;` Not tested.

Comment: @madflow this worked to delete the index, thank you. but why was I unable to view the index when I ran: \di+

Comment: Best guess is that schema was not in the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) which means you would need to schema qualify the search pattern e.g. `\di+ br.*`. Would also explain why `DROP INDEX index_id_test;` did not work.